# Update Propel Generated classes after modifying database

Tags: composer-php, propel

I wanted to update propel generated classes that are present in the model folder as I have modified my database schema (i.e., I have added one column in a table). What are the steps to update the model classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below steps to update propel model classes:

1. Remove all the files inside the `/vendor` folder of your application
2. execute the below command from the folder where `composer.json` exists

   ```
   $ composer update
   ```
3. set the path variable to /path/to/vendor/bin folder
4. Run the propel reverse task to generate schema.xml specifying your database credentials

   ```
    $ propel reverse "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;user=root;password=pwd"
   ```

   Output of above command will be `schema.xml` file
5. Replace your `schema.xml` file in the project with this new one
6. From the command prompt go to the folder where you copied `schema.xml` file and execute below commands.

   ```
   $ propel sql:build
   $ propel model:build
   ```

Thats it. Propel model classes should get updated.

Comment: If you use any characters that aren't bash safe, i.e. `!` in your `password`, you'll get `-bash: !": event not found`.
Using single quotes works fine, though.